# asp.net mvc action method post data except as json data

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a model class named Parcel. This parcel includes **Name**, **CenterPoint** parameters:

```
public class Parcel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object CenterPoint { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting theese parameters from a map. When  I click a parcel center point is calculated and setted in a variable in javascript. **CenterPoint** is a **json** object. **Name** is a plain text data.

I want to save CenterPoint as Json object in database. And when I get CenterPoint again on map, I can draw it.

When I post data to action method as following, my CenterPoint object is coming like this **{object}.**

Actually it should be like this: **{ type="point", x=121.32380004076, y=452.024614968}**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveParcel(Parcel parcel)
    {
        return Json(new {parcel}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

my javascript jode is here:

```
           var postata = {
                    "Name": document.getElementById("name").value,
                    "CenterPoint": document.getElementById("center").value
            };

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "/Parcel/SaveParcel/",
                data: postata,
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
            });
```

How can I save and get JSON as orginally. Or is there is a good way passible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think question is...will JSON deserializer convert your `Point` to an anonymous class (to put it inside a generic `Object` property)? AFAIK no: see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object) for details (with a hand-made solution in case you really need it).

I would define a `Location` class:

```
public class Location
{
    public type { get; set; }
    public float x { get; set; }
    public float y { get; set; }
}
```

Then change `Parcel` to:

```
public class Parcel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Location CenterPoint { get; set; }
}
```

Please note *"...inside a generic `Object` property..."*. Deserializer won't do that but [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm) will do what you need for a `dynamic` object then you may rewrite your `Parcel` class to:

```
public class Parcel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public dynamic CenterPoint { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think that is possible

Comment: @bookmarker not an object. If you don't want to make it strongly typed you can use dynamic instead. See updated post for both references.